# Nginx multiple conditions for rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

my nginx configuration as following

```
  location /eicnews/ {
  set $con "";

  if ($request_uri ~ ^/eicnews\/(.*)$) {
    set $con  A;
  }

  if ($request_uri ~ ^/eicnews\/$) {
    set $con  "${con}B";
  }

  if ($con = A) {
rewrite ^/eicnews\/eicnewscontent_(.*)\.shtml$ http://news.abc.cn/eic/news_$1.shtml permanent;
        }

        if ($con = AB) {
rewrite ^/eicnews\/(.*)$ http://news.abc.cn/eic permanent;

        }

}
```

my configuration means that 
1.if clients request directoty named "/eicnews/" will be rewrited to  url/dir
2.if clients request the files  included the directoty  named "/eicnews/" will be rewrited to url/dir/files

But now there tow kinds file names in "/eicnews/" ,eicnewscontent_xxxx.shtml and eicnewslist_xxxx.shtml ,I wanna if the prefix  "eicnewscontent" files be rewrited to   http://news.abc.cn/eic/news_$1.shtml and the prefix "eicnewslist" will be rewrited to  http://news.abc.cn/eic.

Thank You ALL!!!!

I mean that,there 2 kinds prefix file in the directoty,such as eicnewslist_xxxxx.shtml and eicnewscontent_xxxxx.shtml, prefix "eicnewslist" rewrite to one url,prefix "eicnewscontent" rewrite to the other url.I want it  as following.Syntax is OK. But it doesn't works.

```
location =  /eicnews/ {

        rewrite  ^/eicnews/eicnewslist(_.*\.shtml)$  http://news.smartjs.cn/eic$1 permanent;
    }
    location /eicnews/ {
        rewrite ^/eicnews/eicnewscontent(_.*\.shtml)$ http://news.smartjs.cn/eic/news_xx.shtml$1 permanent;
    }
```

Comment: Inside `location /eicnews/` your first `if` is always true (unless you have some other rewrites that you did not show). In this case your thirds `if` is always false. So, could you explain what URLs do you want to rewrite and to what. With some samples.

Comment: Thanks,I made a typing mistake.In the third if clause"set $con =A not B".I'v corrected it yet :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid `if`s as much as possible. Read http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil.

In your case I would do following:

```
location = /eicnews/ {
    rewrite ^ http://news.abc.cn/eic permanent;
}

location /eicnews/ {
    rewrite ^/eicnews/eicnewscontent(_.*\.shtml)$ http://news.abc.cn/eic/news$1 permanent;
}
```

I'm not sure what you suppose to do with requests to `/eicnews/other-path`.

Comment: You want all of `eicnewslist_ANYTHING` to be redirected to one url `http://news.abc.cn/eic`?

Comment: @XuYuanzhen, I ask once more for **examples**. Please put them in question, It's impossible to read them in comments.

Comment: I had fixed and look forward to your excellent answer.Thanks a lot.